# Enabling multi-org for specific BUs only

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit, multi-org

We have a question regarding a bussiness units hierarchy we are trying to set in MC. We would like to achieve something like this:

> BU A connected to SF org A
>
> BU B (Child of BU A) connected to SF org B
>
> BU C (Child of BU B) not connected to any SF org directly but inheriting
> the connection of its parent (BU B) to SF org B.

As you can see above for BU A and BU B multi org should be enabled, but for BU C it should be disabled.

Is this configuration possible to achieve in MC?

Thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn on multi-org, it will be turned on for all BUs.

To achieve the above setup, you could use two separate API users in SFMC:

- one with access to BU A and connected to org A,
- second one with access to BU B and C and connected to org B.

Verify your setup with SF support before you turn on multi-org, because it cannot be turned off once enabled.

Here’s multi-org FAQ for your reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thansk @zuzannamj for making this clear.